# Eclipse build path / JBoss AS7 Class Loading Exceptions question

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I'm migrating a JBoss AS5 app to AS7.  I was running into NoClassDefFoundErrors due to AS7's redesigned modular class loading design.  I was following the JBoss developer guide on how to resolve class loading exceptions https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide#DeveloperGuide-Resolveclassloadingexceptionsandothererrors , which has you doing things such as adding modules as dependencies in your app's MANIFEST.MF file, but I had a lot of trouble with this.  None of my attempts to resolve my class loading errors using MANIFEST.MF or manually copying jars to my app's WEB-INF/lib/ directory seemed to work.

In Eclipse, I tried right clicking on my project and manually adding classes specified by my class loading errors to my project's JAVA BUILD PATH.  I was able to eliminate all of the class loading errors using this method.  My question is - how is Eclipse storing the build path information and making it available to my maven build?  Is it creating a MANIFEST.MF or jboss-deployment-structure.xml somewhere on the file system using the JAVA BUILD PATH information?  I'd like to find whatever file Eclipse is using to store JAVA BUILD PATH so that I can deploy my application without having to manually add dependencies via Eclipse to my JAVA BUILD PATH.  Thanks.

Comment: This new module stuff is going to be a headache for a year or two to come. Wish i had an answer for you :(.

Comment: Hello, it's been some time since you've asked this question. Are you still having problems? In this case please update your question with a small directory structure of your application and I may try give you a more accurate answer. Hugs.

Answer (score 0):

Messing with MANIFEST.MF in a development environoment sounds horrible. For automatic dependencies management use Maven (its not ideal tool, but it is standard, has nice Eclipse plugin, so, after all, it is not such a pain to use it).

Java build path is stored by Eclipse in a .classpath file in the project directory (note the dot at the beggining). The file looks more or less like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/oscache-2.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/proxool-0.8.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="db/derby.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="db/derbyclient.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

So it can be generated with a simple script if you have a list of dependencies.

Remember that Eclipse loves to cache things. So when you change .classpath file, refresh your project manually (F5), otherwise you would not see any changes.